# Paginate Data from scope

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using a scope to get data from a BelongstoMany relation, is it possible to paginate data from this scope ?

**User Model**

```
public function scopeWithAndWhereHas($query, $relation, $constraint){
        return $query->whereHas($relation, $constraint)
                     ->with([$relation => $constraint]);
    }
```

I'm accessing the scope in a controller like this

```
$transactions  = User::withAndWhereHas('drinks', function($query) use ($status){
    $query->where('status', '1');
  })->paginate(2);
```

The paginate() helper doesn't seem to work.

Comment: what happens when you are calling `paginate(2)` on that?

Comment: It attempts to paginate the data but i notice 'next_page_url' is null and 'last_page' and 'last_page_url' are always 1. All the data is returned on the page without being paginated